# Как посчитать кол-во слов в JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Как сделать переменную, что бы её значение равнялось кол-ву слов в JTextArea?

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные инструменты такой функции не предоставляют. Нужно самому думать как логически выделить в строке слова. На пример, можете попробовать просто посчитать пробелы

```
JTextArea jTextArea=new JTextArea;
int count=0;

for (char element : jTextArea.fetText().toCharArray()){
    if (element == ' ') count++;
}
```